# How to check if an app is running in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have made my app to be background running and it is going to be voip based app

```
Open application's Info.plist file.
Added a new row and type in the Key field "Required background modes".
Expand this array and for Item 0, type in the Value field "App provides Voice over IP services"
```

Now I would like to check, is that working after going in the background?

I have been trying to know this and I have searched for a long time but nothing seems to help...

Please guide me up.

How can I ensure that my app can work even in the background state?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try NSLog-ging while in the background, and check whether the logs are shown in the Console.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to try to make a viop connection to it and see if it responds?